# AngularJS animate dynamic margin

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-animation

I have an element that appears when the user clicks a button elsewhere on the screen.  The element appears to come out of the top of the screen.  The element by default needs to be tucked out of view above the screen, so I will have a margin-top style that is based on the  height of the element (and will be a negative value).  This cannot be hardcoded in css because the element height may vary.  When I click the button, I want the element margin-top to change to 0 and I want a transition animation.

The sample shown on angularJS documentation is for adding a removing a class.  This would work fine if I knew the values to be set and could code them in CSS, however I cannot.  What is the correct way to solve this?

The code below works for displaying and hiding my element using a margin but there is no animation.  How do I trigger an animation here when the margin changes?

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations

```
<a href="" ng-click="showTotals=!showTotals">Quote Total: {{salesPriceTotal + taxesTotal - tradeInsTotal | currency}}</a>

<div class="totals" ng-style="setTopMargin()">
    // totals stuff here.
</div>

$scope.setTopMargin = function() {
    return {
        marginTop: $scope.marginTop
    }
};

$scope.$watch('showTotals', function() {
    var margin = $scope.showTotals ? 10 : -160 + $scope.modelTotals.length * -200;
    $scope.marginTop = margin.toString() + 'px';
});
```

I added the following code per a suggested solution, but this code is never hit.

```
myApp.animation('.totals', function () {
    return {
        move: function (element, done) {
            element.css('opacity', 0);
            jQuery(element).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, done);

            // optional onDone or onCancel callback
            // function to handle any post-animation
            // cleanup operations
            return function (isCancelled) {
                if (isCancelled) {
                    jQuery(element).stop();
                }
            }
        },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations) explains: "The same approach to animation can be used using JavaScript code (jQuery is used within to perform animations)".

So you basically needs to use animate() from jQuery to do what you want.

Comment: I've heard that using jQuery within a controller is a bad practice, and this type of thing should be put in a directive if anywhere.  I'm not sure how the implementation ties in with my existing code above but will look into it.

Comment: see the added code to my question, the animation code is never hit